# Qucs How to add 10uF Polarised Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, qucs

I'm new to this site. I have a small experiment. I did trying to make a circuit from a schema that needs 10uF Polarised Capacitor in the schema. I use Qucs (Quite Universal Circuit Simulator) [qucs.sourceforge.net](http://qucs.sourceforge.net) as the tool. But I couldn't find the Polarised Capacitor there. Does anyone know where is it ?, xD. Hehe sorry I barely learn about E-Engineering. Thanks before
[image]

Comment: Just use a non-polarised one. In most cases it will make no difference at all to the simulation.

Comment: @TomCarpenter oh really ?, I'll try. Thanks tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To transform the component symbol in a polarized capacitor, once you put it in the scheme:

[image]

you double-click to open the properties window.

[image]

There are three options: *C* to the value of capacitor, *V* for initial voltage and *Symbol* to select between neutral and polar.
The *polar* version:

[image]

**Note**: version 0.0.18 of *Qucs*

Comment: Surprising, I didn't know that. Nice answer!! Thanks Martin